# fetch multi dimensional array from php with jquery and parse it

Tags: php, jquery

I have a milti-dimensional array in test.php:

```
$rows=array();
$rows[]=array('test1','test2');
$rows[]=array('test3','test4');
echo json_encode($rows);
```

I want to get them in client side and parse it in Jquery:

```
$.get( "test.php",
    function(data){
        //how can I get data here??
    }
);
```

Comment: Only one way to find out. Go and test your code...

Comment: I will try them and come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$.getJSON
```

Read this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/